# Choosing Django v1.4 app for tagging and categorization

Tags: django, taxonomy, tagging, categorization

I was looking for a tagging/categorization app for a Django project. In past I have used  django-tagging and django-taggit. Looks like they are not being actively maintained. I also saw a few others but they are either unmaintained of don't really reach the functionality of these two.

The kind of project  I was working on for past year did not require tagging like functionality therefore I am out of touch in this area.

So before starting on writing my own app I thought, I would ask the mighty Stackoverflow community if there are any maintained forks of these apps or if there others similar to them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure why an app has to be actively maintained to be useable? Both apps have been around for a couple of years, are stable, feature-full and great at what they set out to do. Is there a particular feature you need that neither of these apps offer?

Comment: I have the same exact question... when you have chosen one, I would be glad if you would share your rationale and experience. :) [The one that seems closer to my needs is `django-taxonomy` but I haven't play around with it just yet...

Answer (score 1):

I've used both on different projects, too with different Django versions. There are some forks to. For instance, for django-tagging there is [**django-tagging-ng**](https://github.com/svetlyak40wt/django-tagging-ng) that provides multilingual, synonyms and hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply refer to opencomparison for package comparisons of django apps here - http://django.opencomparison.org/grids/g/tagging/

And I would go with `django-tagging` and add in `django-tagging-ext` optionally.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? 
https://github.com/bkjones/django-taxonomy